# Using RE2 expressions in matches in GCP Cloud Armor rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, re2, google-cloud-armor

Hi I'm trying to set up a rule in a Cloud Armor security policy to block requests where the Host is set to an IP address.  This should be fairly straight forward, except I'm just getting an error in the web console when trying to apply the rule.

Here's the RE2 code for the custom rule:

```
!has(request.headers["Host"]) ||
request.headers["Host"] == "" ||
request.headers["Host"].matches('(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)')
```

We get the Host header and then use .matches() against the Host header string.  The regex is fairly standard stuff but I don't get why the console is balking with this kind of error message:

```
1:34: token recognition error at: ''(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.'
3:82: extraneous input '3' expecting {'}', ',', IDENTIFIER}
3:84: mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, 'in', '==', '!=', '<', '<=', '>=', '>', '&&', '||', '[', '{', '.', '-', '?', '+', '*', '/', '%%'}
3:28: token recognition error at: '|2'
3:40: token recognition error at: '|['
3:58: token recognition error at: '')'
3:81: expected a qualified name
3:81: undeclared reference to '*error*' (in container '')
1:1: ERROR: Cloud Armor rule matcher expression:1:33: token recognition error at: ''(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.'
```

I've been using the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, it seems that I had to double escape the `\` before the `.`.

Thus the custom rule was now:

```
!has(request.headers["Host"]) ||
request.headers["Host"] == "" ||
request.headers["Host"].matches('(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)')
```

Comment: This example (use case) should be part of the documentation. Did you verify that the rule works as expected using a tool like **curl** or **postman**? Once you do, click the feedback button and submit your solution here: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_for_a_request_uri_that_matches_a_regular_expression

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I've just run some checks with `curl`, specifically the following and can see them all triggering the above rule:
`curl -0 -H 'user-agent: testing' http://130.211.x.x/`
`curl -H 'Host: ' -H 'user-agent: testing' http://test-domain.com/`
`curl -H 'Host: 130.211.x.x' -H 'user-agent: testing' http://test-domain.com/`

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. That will mark the question as answered and can be used with future questions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still waiting for it to let me accept my own answer, there's some pretty lengthy wait time on it.